# What is this jQuery doing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would call myself an intermediate jQuery developer, but I'm confused about what this line (from Twitter's Bootstrap) is doing:

```
$tip.find('.help-popover-title')[ $.type(title) == 'object' ? 'append' : 'html' ](title)
```

Specifically, the part between the square brackets. Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Are you asking about the conditional operator?

Comment: I would guess that OP's confusion is (mine was) is at the $jqueryobject[function](argument) syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tip // tip object
.find('.help-popover-title') // find elements of this class

// if the data inside the title variable is an object
// use the append method otherwise use html method
[$.type(title)  == 'object' ? 'append': 'html']  

(title) // lastly, execute the selected function and pass in the title var
```

The inner statement uses a ternary operator.  It's basically a single line `if..else` statement

```
x = 5;

x === 5 ? true : false; // true
x === 4 ? true: false; // false
```

Since the selected method is inside the brackets, you can use a string to select a method
It's equalvelent to:

```
$tip['append'](title) === $tip.append(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

The big concept here is that object properties can be accessed not just literally and directly but also with square brackets containing a String (literal or variable) with the name of the property. Also, functions are always properties of an object—even if only the global context.

First, check out value-based properties:

```
var myobj = {
   animal: 'frog',
   color: 'blue',
   fly: function() {/*fly*/},
   hide: function() {/*hide*/}
};
alert(myobj.animal); // alerts 'frog';
var prop = 'color';
alert(myobj[prop]); // alerts 'blue';
```

Then note that when the property values are functions it doesn't change anything. They are still accessed the same way:

```
myobj.fly() // run function fly
prop = 'hide';
myobj[prop]() // run function named in variable 'prop', which is 'hide';
```

So ultimately, the code fragment you posted is just checking the type of the `title` variable and choosing the appropriate function to make it a child of the found element. If the `title` is an object, `append it`. If it's not (it must be text) then use the `html` function instead. It was coded this way to save duplicating code or declaring a new variable.

Ternary operators are the expressive forms of normal procedural `if` statements (that is, they evaluate to something rather than controlling flow). The following example will show this:

```
if (a == 1) {return 'yes';} else {return 'no';}
return (a == 1) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

VB's `Iif()` function and Excel's `IF()` worksheet function are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It's an inline if statement, otherwise called a ternary operator. Basically, if the type of title is 'object' then it's getting the index 'append', otherwise the index 'html'. Hope this what you meant by your question.